# Show that the equation reduces to the form $(\tan(A)-m)(\tan(B)-n)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given that $\cos(A), \cos(B)$ and $\beta$ are non-zero, show that the
> equation $$\alpha\sin(A-B)+\beta\cos(A+B)=\gamma\sin(A+B)$$ reduces to
> the from $$(\tan(A)-m)(\tan(B)-n)=0$$
>
> where $m$ and $n$ are independent of $A$ and $B$ if and only if
> $\alpha^2=\beta^2+\gamma^2$.

Workings: $$\alpha\sin(A-B)+\beta\cos(A+B)=\gamma\sin(A+B)$$

$$\iff \alpha(\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(B)\sin(B))+\beta(\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B))=\gamma(\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B))$$
$$\iff \alpha(\tan(A)-\tan(B)) + \beta(1-\tan(A)\tan(B))=\gamma(\tan(A)+\tan(B))$$
$$\iff(\alpha-\gamma)\tan(A) - (\alpha+\gamma)\tan(B)=\beta(\tan(A)\tan(B)-1)$$
$$\iff (\alpha-\gamma)^2\tan^2(A)-2(\alpha^2-\gamma^2)\tan(A)\tan(B)+(\alpha+\gamma)^2\tan(B)=\beta^2(\tan^2(A)\tan^2(B)-2\tan(A)\tan(B)+1) $$

Using $\alpha^2=\beta^2+\gamma^2$

$$(\alpha-\gamma)^2\tan^2(A) + (\alpha+\gamma)^2\tan^2(B)=\beta^2(\tan^2(A)\tan^2(B)+1)$$

I don't know how to proceed from here. Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve for the quantity $\tan(A)\tan(B)$

$$\tan(A)\tan(B) = n\tan(A)+m \tan(B) -mn\tag{1} $$

Using your line...

$$\alpha(\tan(A)-\tan(B)) + \beta(1-\tan(A)\tan(B))=\gamma(\tan(A)+\tan(B))$$

Let $p\equiv \frac \alpha \beta \text{ and }p\equiv  \frac \gamma \beta$

$$\iff  \tan(A)\tan(B) =1 - q(\tan(A)+\tan(B)) - p(\tan(A)-\tan(B))$$
$$\iff  \tan(A)\tan(B) = 1-(p+q) \tan(A)+(p-q) \tan(B) \tag{2}$$
Equating coefficients between (1) and (2) gives...
$$n=-(p+q) \text{ and }  m=(p-q) \text{ and } mn=-1$$
$$p^2 - q^2=1 \iff \gamma^2=\alpha^2 + \beta^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

From your third $\iff$, we have that
$$(\alpha-\gamma)\tan A-(\alpha+\gamma)\tan B=\beta(\tan A\tan B-1)$$
Then, if $\beta^2=\alpha^2-\gamma^2=(\alpha-\gamma)(\alpha+\gamma)$, the given equation can be expressed as
$$(\sqrt{a}\tan A+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{b}\tan B-\sqrt{a})=0$$
where $a=\alpha-\gamma$, and $b=\alpha+\gamma$. So, $\tan A=-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}$, and $\tan B=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$, each being both independent of $A, B$.

Comment: I think you may have made a typo. Shouldn't it be $(\sqrt{a}\tan A-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{b}\tan B+\sqrt{a})=0$. But regardless, thank you for the solution. One final question if you don't mind, I am quite new to if and only if questions and I was wondering whether it would be necessary to show the other direction also? That is, we assume the conclusion and prove it goes in the reverse direction also?

Comment: I think it's not a typo. The first equation is same as $$\sqrt{ab}\tan A\tan B-a\tan A+b\tan B-\sqrt{ab}$$, which gives the same expression as the second. For your second question, I'm not sure whether how to prove the other direction. You probably should prove it for iff type of questions, but I can't think of a way to show that the **only** possible way for $m, n$ to be independent with $A, B$ is to have $\alpha^2=\beta^2+\gamma^2$. I suggest you look at the other answer below, I think he/she proves it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks!